# the ko viewmodel is updated on js but not displaying in html view

Tags: html, asp.net, knockout.js

I'm just starting to use knockout js and after lots tets, I can't solve this : the js viewmodel is updated by my function js, but no visual variation on the browser is displayed. This only happens to me for this model called TableViewModel, for the other models, the addition of other elements works correctly on view.

in the past I tried to refer at the child elements of this view model, but I don't have the necessary information to modify the table interested (the table is the father on the elements that are viewModelGroups).
I have search on https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/  and few forum but I did not solve this problem.

This is my short function on js file (into the tableViewModel) :

```
TableViewModel = (function() {
   function TableViewModel(data) {
       var g, group;
       this.id = data.id;
       //...
       //...
       group = (function() {
           var j, len, ref, results;
           ref = data.Group;
           results = [];
           for (j = 0, len = ref.length; j < len; j++) {
               g = ref[j];
               results.push(new GroupViewModel(g));
           }
           return results;
       })();
       this.Group = group;
       return;
   }

   TableViewModel.prototype.newObject = function() {            
       var self = this;
       var ggrrpp = new GroupViewModel(self.Group[0]);
       this.Group.push(ggrrpp);    
   };
   TableViewModel.prototype.toJS = function() {
       var group;
       return {
           id: this.id,
           //...
           //...
           Group: (function() {
               var j, len, ref, results;
               ref = this.Group;
               results = [];
               for (j = 0, len = ref.length; j < len; j++) {
                   group = ref[j];
                   results.push(group.toJS());
               }
               return results;
           }).call(this)
       };
    }; 
    return TableViewModel;    
})();
```

and this is my html(aspx)part used to call the function above :

```
<div class="row" data-bind="with: Table">
...
...
<i class="config-button fa fa-plus" title="Adding object" aria-hidden="true"
 data-bind="click: function() { newObject(); }"> </i>
   <div data-bind="foreach: Group"> 
   ...
   ...
```

in the newObject function, the push works and add the object in the group list (each time it is called it contains the previous addition)...but the view does not change.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: any particular reason behind making your view model a self invoked function and not calling `ko.applyBindings` on the view?

Comment: @gkb this is usually how a typescript class traspiled to constructor function looks like.

Comment: ko.applyBinding is used for the viemodel container, this viewmodel contains all viewmodel including tableViewModel. I have done similar operations in child models and the view has been correctly updated...this problem occurs only in TableViewModel

Answer (score 0):

If you want the DOM to be updated when a new item is added to `Group`, you need to convert it to an [`observableArray`](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)

```
this.Group = ko.observableArray(group);
```

Also, inside `newObject`, you can't use bracket notation directly on `observableArray`. You need to get the value using the parenthesis first and then use the indexer:

```
var ggrrpp = new GroupViewModel(self.Group()[0])
```